# New instance of class called within class -

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a new instance of a constructor, from a method of the Class itself. In compiled JS it works, but in TS I get the error `cannot use new with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature`.

To explain the problem I'll simplify my class:

```
class Saver {

    toSave: { obj1 : Object, obj2 ?: Object };

    constructor(obj : { obj1 : Object, obj2 ?: Object }) {
        this.toSave = obj;
        return this;
    }
    prepare() {

        if(obj.obj2) new Saver(obj.obj2).save(); // here I get the error
        return this;
    }
    save() {
        // I do stuff
    }
}

var testObj = { obj1 : aFakeObject, obj2 : anotherFakeObj };
new Saver(testObj).prepare().save();
```

In the `*.d.ts` file:

```
export interface construct {}

export interface SaverConstruct extends construct {
    new(obj ?: { obj1 : Object, obj2 ?: Object });
}

class Saver {

    constructor();

    private prepare() : void;
    public save() : void;
}
```

I've been using this logic for quite some time, so I'm pretty confident that in JS that is possible. How can I implement it correctly in TS?

Comment: The posted code doesn't reproduce the errors you're describing. Please edit with a self-contained snippet that demonstrates the problem to be addressed.

Comment: You are right... Which is frustrating because it means that the code should work... Probably this has something to do with the typescript plugin, rather than the code...